# rename columns according to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 lists of data frames and I want to add a suffix to each column according to whether it belongs to a certain list of data frames. its all in order, so the first item in the suffix list should be appended to the columns of data frames in the first list of data frames etc. I am trying here but its adding each item in the suffix list to each column.

In the expected output

- all columns in dfs in cat_a need group1 appended
- all columns in dfs in cat_b need group2 appended
- all columns in dfs in cat_c need group3 appended

data and code are here

```
df1, df2, df3, df4 = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=('a', 'b')), 
                      pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=('c', 'd')),
                      pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=('e', 'f')),
                      pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=('g', 'h')))

cat_a = [df1, df2]
cat_b = [df3, df4, df2]
cat_c = [df1]

suffix =['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
dfs = [cat_a, cat_b, cat_c]

for x, y in enumerate(dfs):
    for i in y:
        suff=suffix
        i.columns = i.columns + '_' + suff[x]
```

thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Is it intentional that `df1` and `df2` map to multiple groups? i.e. should they have column names like: `col_group1_group2`?

Comment: it is intentional. it doesnt really make sense here i know but there are some columns (and infact dataframes) that have the same names. its not ideal its just a product of how its stored previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to have multiple suffixes for some dataframes, I think this is what you want?:

```
suffix_mapper = {
    'group1': [df1, df2],
    'group2': [df3, df4, df2],
    'group3': [df1]
}

for suffix, dfs in suffix_mapper.items():
    for df in dfs:
        df.columns = [f"{col}_{suffix}" for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: my code did that but i only want one suffix per dataframe - i need to assume that the dataframes, based on their position in the lists, actually have nothing to do with eachother

Comment: Lol wait but I just asked that above? So it sounds like the real problem is getting this suffix mapping correct? Am I correct in assuming that df1 should have suffix `group3` instead of `group1` because that came earlier in the suffix ordering? It would be helpful if you added a couple examples of the exact suffixes you expect for some dataframes in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

[Brian Joseph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69799183) is great*, but I'd like to point out that you were very close, you just weren't renaming the columns correctly. Your last line should be like this:

```py
i.columns = [col + '_' + suff[x] for col in i.columns]
```

instead of this:

```py
i.columns = i.columns + '_' + suff[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you're not taking a copy of the dataframe so each cat dataframe is referencing a df dataframe multiple times.

Try:

```
cat_a = [df1.copy(), df2.copy()]
cat_b = [df3.copy(), df4.copy(), df2.copy()]
cat_c = [df1.copy()]
```